# Button Click does not work properly - how to fix that?

Tags: android

just started to learn about building android apps. Initial using Eclipse and get this error by creating my first code:

> The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener)  in the type View
>   is not applicable for the arguments  (new OnClickListener(){})

Searched a while, tried to fix imports, etc. Here is my code:

```
package com.example.test1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button plus, minus;
TextView ergebnis;
int count;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aHead);
    minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bMinus);
    ergebnis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOut);
    count = 0;

    plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count += 1;
            ergebnis.setText("Anzahl: " + count);
        }
    });

    minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count -= 1;
            ergebnis.setText("Anzahl: " + count);
        }
    });


  }
}
```

Comment: post your `activity_main.xml`

Comment: No need of `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;`

Comment: Why use Eclipse, Use Android Studio, or turn on Automatic imports of classes.

Comment: The onClick() method is overriden so there should be an @Override indicator.

`@Override


public void onClick(View v) {
       // Your code here }`

Answer (score 2):

First of all import this

```
import android.view.View;
```

Then set listener for the button override OnClick Method

```
YourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Your Stuff
            }
        });
```